# Getting Top 10 Highest Numbers From Array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am having a bit of a issue. I have an NSMutableDictionary with 10 NSMutableArrays in it. Each array has somewhere between 0-10 numbers which could each be any integer, e.g. 12 or 103.

What I need to do is get the top 10 highest numbers from across each of the arrays. The trouble is, I need to keep a reference of the array it came from in the dictionary (the key) and the index position of the number from the array it came form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way, is to sort the array in Descending order, and then grab the first 10 indexes

Or if they are inside dictionaries, iterate the dictionary `allValues`, grab all the arrays, add all the elements inside a common array, and sort that

Comment: I understand this would seem obvious and relatively simple, however, I can sort them as I need to retain (or at least be able to reference) the top 10 numbers original indexes.

Comment: when you get the top 10 items, you could create a new array that holds the indexes of the original items in the original array

Comment: What is confusing me though, is how when sorting the numbers can you get the index of the top numbers before they have been shuffled?

Comment: you dont really get the indexes, you use, [originalArray indexOfObject:(here add any object of the newly sorted array)];

Comment: This has worked well, until I have duplicate numbers. For example, if there are two or more zeros, and I use the method use just suggested, it thinks all zeros belong to the same index. Any way of getting around this?

Comment: even if you have two duplicate zeros, it will not change the effect, since array holds objects and not numbers, then every zero will have its own NSNumber instance

Comment: Odd, just when I create my array which holds all the original indexes of my sorted numbers, as an example, all the eros share the same index of the first zero.

Comment: Best solution is take a min heap of size 10. Replace the root node with current node, if the current node is bigger than root node.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the data structure you want to end up with is an array of objects, where each object is functionally similar to an "index path" except that it's composed of a string (key) and a value (offset).

Assuming that the actual search for highest numbers isn't in question, then I'd suggest creating one of these objects whenever you find a candidate number so that, once the top ten are found, the objects can be used as back-pointers to the numbers' source locations.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Use the top 10 numbers found as back pointers? But what if there are duplicate numbers? How would you match it to the correct original index?

Comment: Use the object containing the dictionary key and the array index as a path to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You have to short your array in descending order using **'C'** logic. Here i'm going to give an example according to your condition....

```
// adding 20 elements in an array, suppose this is your original array (array1).
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(i*4)];
    [array1 addObject:str];
}

//make a copy of your original array 
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array1];


// this is the array which will get your sorting list
NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//declare an integer for compare as a maximum number and it to 0 initially
int max = 0;


// this is the logic to sort an array
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<[array2 count];j++)
    {
        int f = [[array2 objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
        if(max<f)
        {
            max = f;
        }
    }

    NSString *str = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:max]stringValue];

    //max has a maximum value then add it to array3 and remove from array2 
    //for a new shorting

    [array3 addObject:str];
    [array2 removeObject:str];

    // set 0 to max again
    max = 0;
}

    //now after all procedure print the **array3**
    // and you will get all the objects in descending order,
    //you can take top **10** variables from **array3**

    NSLog(@"your sorting array %@", **array3**);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some sort of homework :)

So you have this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* source = [@{
    @"1" : @[ @10, @20, @100 … ],
    @"2" : @[ @8, @42, @17 … ]
} mutableCopy];
```

So lets start by creating another arrangement:

```
NSMutableArray* numbers = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSArray* array in source.allValues)
{
    for (NSNumber* number in array)
    {
        [numbers addObject: @{ @"number" : number, @"parent" : array }];
    }
}
```

This is what we get:

```
@[
    @{ @"number" : @10, @"parent" : <array> },
    @{ @"number" : @20, @"parent" : <array> },
    …
]
```

Now we can sort and find the numbers you wanted.

```
[numbers sortUsingComparator: ^( id lhs, id rhs ){
    return [((NSDictionary*) rhs)[@"number"] compare: ((NSDictionary*) lhs)[@"number"]];
}];
NSArray* topNumbers = [numbers subarrayWithRange: NSMakeRange( 0, 10 )];
```

Here we are. topNumbers contains the numbers you needed along the source array.

This is quite a naive way to do it. It can be optimized both in CPU time and memory usage by a fair amount. But hey, keep it simple is not a bad thing.

Not addressed: what if the tenth and eleventh numbers are equal? (adressed here: [Pick Out Specific Number from Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177585/pick-out-specific-number-from-array)) range checks. not tested, not even compiled. ;)

Comment: This line `[numbers addObject: @{ @"number" : number, @"parent" : array }];` is throwing an error because of the first `@`, but why? Sorry I haven't seen an objet being added to an array like this before. (Thanks for your answer!)

Comment: Xcode 4.4/4.5 with literals. You can use NSDictionary -dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: instead, and NSArray -arrayWithObjects: instead, but so much verbose. @{} -> NSDictionary, @[] -> NSArray, @10 -> NSNumber.

Comment: Ahh! That will be the issue, Im on 4.3.3. Thanks for explaining that. Also, if Im not mistaken, does the `numbers` array not want to be a dictionary?

Comment: Also, won't having multiple objects with the same key fail?

Comment: You'll love the literals when you'll be able to use them. [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: ...] sucks so much. Well. I do not know what are the keys of your original dictionary. It doesn't matter anyway, I do not use them. `numbers` is an array I can sort, containing an entry for every number in your original dictionary's arrays. Each entry is a dictionary containing the number (value for key @"number") and the source array (key @"parent"). No conflicts there. It's an index. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the arrays creating an object/structure for each element, consisting of the numeric "key" value and the "path" (array indices) to the element.  Sort the objects/structures so created.  (This is referred to as a "tag sort".)

The other approach, if you only need the top N values (where N << total number of entries) is to create an array of N elements, consisting of the above key and path info.  Scan through all the arrays and compare each array element to the smallest key of the N currently stored.  If you find an element larger than the smallest stored, replace the smallest stored and sort the N elements to select a new smallest stored.