# Pick Out Specific Number from Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsarray

I have a bunch of NSArrays filled with numbers. Is there anyway that I can somehow grab a specific number, specifically like:

Third highest number in array, or 24th highest number in array?

But I don't want to just grab the number, I also need a reference to the index it was in the array as well, if that can be retained in the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Third highest number in array, or 24th highest number in array?

Create a temporary copy of the array and sort it ascending.
Get the number at index `3-1` or `24-1`.

> I also need a reference to the index it was in the array as well

Now use `indexOfObject:` or `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` to get the actual index.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the sorted `numbers` array from my answer here [Getting Top 10 Highest Numbers From Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177564/getting-top-10-highest-numbers-from-array) :

```
NSUInteger wanted = 24 or anything;

NSUInteger count = 0;
NSNumber* previous = nil;
for (NSDictionary* entry in numbers)
{
    if ( wanted == 1 ) return entry;

    if (previous == nil)
    {
        // first entry
        previous = entry[@"number"];
        ++ count;

        continue;
    }

    // same number? skip it.
    if ( entry[@"number"] isEqualTo: previous ) continue;

    // if we get here, we found a different number we may be interested in

    ++ count;

    if ( count == wanted ) return entry;
}

// nothing found
return nil;
```

The result is a line in the `numbers` array from the previous question. An array of the form `@[ @"number" : @<number>, @"parent" : <source array> ]`.

Comment: btw, you can adapt that code to find the 10 first unique highest numbers in your dictionary. Use the equality test (with a negation) to increment count instead of skipping, and add the entry in an array till count == 10 instead of returning the entry. Easy enough.